# How to parse output of pipe in real time?

Tags: bash, shell

When I pipe two commands, it seems the first command must finish before the second command could parse the output.

For example,

```
$ ping -c 5 10.11.12.13 | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

I expect it would generate output every second, but not. Is it true or I miss something (e.g., buffering effect)?

The problem is: if the first command runs over long period of time and I want to parse the output in real time. How to do it using shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the first command to become unbuffered by using a command like [`unbuffer`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) (from the `expect` package) or [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf). This way, it will flush its output after each line, rather than after it outputs e.g. 4096 bytes.